# $u$ harmonic can be represented as sum of $f+\bar{g}$, $f,g$ holomorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, harmonic-functions

On this [pdf (page 5)](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~tkc/complex_2007/Chapter1.pdf):

> If $u$ is harmonic on a disk then it can be represented as $f+\bar{g}$
>   where $f,g$ are holomorphic.

I could not follow this line of proof:[image]

What does mean to integrate wirtinger derivatives, and wrt $\bar{z}$? May someone elaborate the details?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ \frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$

Comment: I know that definition and I still don't understand the equality...

Comment: It's basically the same idea as $z+\bar z = 2 Re\ z$  Since $u(x,y)$ is the real part of the analytic function $f$, it can be recovered as $(f(z)+f(\bar z))/2$ but here you're not trying to get $u$ but its derivative

Comment: Do you mind writing out the details?

Answer (score 0):

Working backwards using the definitions for Wirtinger derivatives and complex differentials 
\begin{align}
&\int_{\gamma} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} u(z) dz+\int_{\gamma} \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} u(z) d\bar z &= \\
&= \int _{\gamma} \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) u(x,y) (dx+idy) + \int _{\gamma} \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) u(x,y) (dx-idy)\\
&= \int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(x,y)dx +\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{2i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} u(x,y)dx +\int_{\gamma}\frac{i}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(x,y)dy +\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} u(x,y)dy \\ 
&+ \int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(x,y)dx
-\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} u(x,y)dx  
-\int_{\gamma}\frac{i}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(x,y)dy 
+\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} u(x,y)dy \\ 
&=\int_{\gamma} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(x,y) dx+\int_{\gamma} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} u(x,y) dy \\
&= \int_0^{1}u'(\gamma(t))\gamma '(t)dt \\
&= \int_0^{1}\frac{d}{dt}u(\gamma(t))dt
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks but I did get this part, what I didn't get was how the last equality follows. Do you mind writing out last equality?

Comment: Sorry.  Which equality is that?

Comment: The original equality, so why $\int \partial u / \partial z \, dz + \int \partial u / \partial \bar{z} \, d \bar{z} = \sum \alpha_n z^{n+1} + \overline{\sum \gamma_n z^{n+1} } $ where the constants are giving in op.

Comment: From your pdf reference $\partial u/\partial z$ is holomorphic (satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equations).  Similarly $\partial u/\partial \bar z$. Expand as power series $\partial u/\partial z = \sum b_nz^n$ and $\partial u/\partial \bar z=\overline{\sum c_nz^n}$.  Term-by-term integration yields the $\sum b_nz^{n+1}/(n+1)$ and $\overline{\sum c_nz^{n+1}/(n+1)}$.  The latter can probably be realized as the conjugate of the integral of the conjugate.

Comment: What I don't understand is how this integration step is written out precisely...

Comment: The series should actually use $z_1\in\Bbb{D}$.  The first series should be clear, it's just term-by-term integration.  The second is the conjugate of term-by-term integration of the conjugate.  (The conjugate of $dx-idy$ is $dx+idy$, and conjugation commutes with integration.)

Comment: May you write out the conjugation integration part? Sorry for causing the trouble, but I'm still unclear.

Comment: That part is easy (why it works may be harder to see).  Take the complex conjugate of $\partial u/\partial \bar z=\overline{\sum c_nz^n}$ to get $\sum c_nz^n$.  Integrate term-by-term to get $\sum c_nz^{n+1}/(n+1)$.  Take the complex ocnjugate again to get $\overline{\sum c_nz^{n+1}/(n+1)}$